# Does Connection.setAutoCommit(true) work for SQL stored procedures and functions?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

DB is Oracle.

I want to use `Connection.setAutoCommit` for `SQL` stored procedures and functions. Will it work?

For calling procedures I use `CallableStatement`

Answer (score 0):

It won't work , connection.setAutoCommit(true), in this connection is a Java Object. You can't use same in the stored procedures.

we have a sql system variable named autocommit , if we set it as on when we write the stored procedures , your procedure will autocommit the results what ever you are trying to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works. Actually auto-commit is on by default. This [chapter](http://oreilly.com/catalog/jorajdbc/chapter/ch19.html) will give you an idea but to save you some time:

> By default, JDBC's auto-commit feature is on, which means that each SQL statement is committed as it is executed. If more than one SQL statement is executed by your program, then a small performance increase can be achieved by turning off auto-commit.

Read the CallableStatement part too:

> As you may recall, CallableStatement objects are used to execute database stored procedures. I've saved CallableStatement objects until last, because they are the slowest performers of all the JDBC SQL execution interfaces. This may sound counterintuitive, because it's commonly believed that calling stored procedures is faster than using SQL, but that's simply not true. Given a simple SQL statement, and a stored procedure call that accomplishes the same task, the simple SQL statement will always execute faster. Why? Because with the stored procedure, you not only have the time needed to execute the SQL statement but also the time needed to deal with the overhead of the procedure call itself.

I think it will help you to take decisions concerning your application's performance.

Answer (score -1):

In a word: yes.  Just make sure that you don't embed transaction logic in the stored procedure.  Leave it all up to the JDBC driver or transaction manager.

There's nothing like trying it for yourself and seeing.  I think that's even better than asking questions here.